# Is the Debian with Raspberry Pi Desktop available as a 64bit download

Tags: raspberry-pi-desktop

I downloaded the Debian with Raspberry Pi Desktop to install on my laptop so I had the same environment on my laptop and Raspberry Pis. However, I find that the installed Java version is a 32 bit executable but I need a 64 bit executable on my laptop. I downloaded a 64 bit version of OpenJDK but the executables will not run. So I assume the Debian with Raspberry Pi Desktop download is a 32 bit version. Is there a 64 bit version available?

Comment: Everybody tells me the bad news that Rpi4B Raspbian buster is only 32 bit.  No 64 bit version is available for Rpi4B buster.

Comment: It's DebIan with a special desktop. Go and ask in a DebIan forum.

Comment: Problem with that is the Pi desktop isn't available in Debian AFAICT -- of course, not giving it a name makes it a bit hard to search for, but searching for package names including "pi" or "raspberry" don't turn anything up: https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=pi&searchon=names&suite=stable&section=all  Searching Raspbian turns up "raspberrypi-ui-mods: Config to customise the LXDE UI", which implies it is no longer a true fork like PIXEL was.  I'd **just install Debian w/ LXDE.**  It won't be exactly the same but the functionality should be very similar.